# Hedge against Oil industry?

Tags: investing, diversification

Since I work for an oil and gas producer in Canada, I receive company shares as a performance bonus, resulting in a disproportionate amount of oil investments in my current portfolio. Is there a good hedge to the oil industry that will help to diversify my portfolio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the company shares are not restricted, you could simply hedge yourself by selling them.

Otherwise, an easy (but maybe not optimal) approach could be purchasing Proshares [DDG](http://www.proshares.com/funds/dug.html) or [DUG](http://www.proshares.com/funds/dug.html) ETFs, assuming that the US and Canadian industries are correlated. [HED](http://www.horizonsetfs.com/pub/en/etfs/http://www.horizonsetfs.com/pub/en/etfs/?etf=HED&tab=overview) may work as a Canada-focused hedge, but not sure it is liquid enough.